Cannot login with OAuth discord provider from non-host device (Auth.js)
I am trying to simply test my web app from my phone (note: from a dev environment; not production) , but I cannot seem to login with my discord account on it. I have no problems signing in with my discord account when doing so from the same device as the one hosting my app. But as soon as I get to the page from a separate device using the host's IP address and proper port number, it does not work as expected.
I added the redirect URL to http://[IP address]:3000/api/auth/callback/discord, so that I could do it from my phone and that did let me get to the 1st image screen (which I could not at first). But after clicking authorize, I get redirected to a screen that looks like the 2nd image.


I expect to be sent back to my app, fully authorized. But I never receive any authorization whatsoever
The server log produces this error after clicking "authorize":
error {
  error: 'invalid_grant',
  error_description: 'Invalid "redirect_uri" in request.'
}
[auth][error] CallbackRouteError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#callbackrouteerror
[auth][cause]: Error: TODO: Handle OAuth 2.0 response body error
    at handleOAuth (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/callback/oauth/callback.js:89:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Module.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/callback/index.js:35:41)
    at async AuthInternal (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:42:24)
    at async Auth (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:126:34)
    at async C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63809
    at async eU.execute (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53964)
    at async eU.handle (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:65062)
    at async doRender (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1333:42)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1543:40)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1463:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1856:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1894:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:911:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:271:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:807:17)
    at async C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:331:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:151:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:328:24)
    at async invokeRender (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:163:21)
    at async handleRequest (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:342:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:366:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (C:\SourceCode\repos\TriviaWebApp\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:140:13)
[auth][details]: {
  "provider": "discord"
}

Edit:
After more investigation, if I type in the host PC's IP into the browser search bar (on the host PC) rather than using "localhost", I get the exact same error that I get on my phone. I'm not sure why this error occurs.

With the server-side OAuth login flow, the redirect_uri value used in the API call that exchanges the received code for a token, must be the exact same one you used when invoking the login dialog. The error message suggests that you did not use the same one.

I found a solution. I made my dev script next dev -H [IP address] to change the host name to my IP rather than localhost. The documentation mentions this here. Though I am still not really sure why this is necessary when I was still able to grab the site via LAN.

Excellent. Thank you for posting this issue and your solution. I was struggling with the same issue.

Glad it helped!

The error Invalid "redirect_uri" in request in this context means the redirect URL you are using doesn't match the one registered in your Discord app settings. You can log in from the device hosting your app because the redirect URL matches.
However, when you try from another device, it fails because the redirect URL differs.
You registered the URL with one IP address (ip-1), but now you are using a different IP address (ip-2). Make sure the redirect URL you use (http://[IP address]:3000/api/auth/callback/discord) is the same as the one registered in the Discord Developer Portal. Discord needs the exact match to work correctly.

I believe the redirect URL and the one I have in the Dev Portal match! It's weird in the 2nd screenshot after it errors out it appears that it tried to connect me to localhost for some reason. Even though the redirect link is displayed in the 1st screenshot I provided. In fact after more investigation, if I type in the host PC's IP into the browser search bar rather than "localhost", I get the exact same error that I get on my phone. I'm going to update the question with this information
